# Loading constants at execution, once or twice?

Tags: c++

I'm a bit confused about loading the executable file generated by C++. I'm putting a huge constant string table into the target executable file. The data should be embedded in the executable file (no external file).

```
struct DataRecord
{
    unsigned char n1;
    unsigned char n2;
    std::string text;
};

static const DataRecord data[] = {
    {1, 2, "Hello"},
    {1, 3, "Hi"},
    {1, 4, "Bye"}
    .
    .
    VERY LONG LIST    
    .
    .
};
```

After compiling and generating the code when we run it, two scenarios can be happen:

1. OS loads the huge executable file (takes time), then, runs the program, after that, the program has the array `data` ready to use.
2. OS loads the huge executable file (takes time), then, runs the program, after that, the program has to make the table and load string literals and construct those `std::string` objects (takes time).

It's obvious that the second one is slower than the first one.

- How to know which one will be happen?
- What's the best approach to have a huge array of embedded data (tradeoff: speed and space)?
- Is it useful to use tool objcopy (I don't have any experience with it)?

*I'm using gcc 4.7+, the targeted OSs are Windows/Linux/Android(NDK)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, constructors will have to be called. The constructors for the strings in your example can not be "done at compile-time". [Edit: For the reason that `std::string` will have to call the `operator new()` to allocate memory (or in other ways allocate memory, although this can SOMETIMES be avoided for short strings, it's unlikely that this decision can be derived sufficiently that the compiler can build the correct data structures "in place" -- end edit]

In this particular case, you could avoid the construction by using `const char *` instead of `std::string`, but that assumes the string is not going to be modified, which may of course be a stretch [and if you need all the strings to be a `std::string` before it is being used, and you use all the string in the large table, there's little, if any, benefit].

By the way, (in most operating systems) the program does not load code "all the code in one big go, takes a long time". Instead, it loads the "entry-point" (in a block of 4KB that is the 4KB-aligned block of code that holds the entry-point). Everything else is "demand loaded" - that is, it's loaded as it's needed.

Comment: since the array is const I think using const char * is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Plain old data (POD) can be prepared at compile and link time and stored in the executable file, so that it only needs to be loaded into memory to be ready for use. However, any member data for classes with constructors is likely to need the constructors to be called.

I compiled the code with Apple clang 4.0 for x86_64, examined the generated code, and stepped through some of its execution. It does call string constructors and does call `malloc`.

In theory, an aggressive C++ implementation could move most of the work to compile and link time, but you should generally expect that data such as this will result in calling constructors and memory allocation at program start.